# Table is still exist after dropping it and the whole database too

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, qsqltablemodel

I get this message after I dropped the table and the database completely

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 12
>   There is already an object named 'Users' in the database

I tried to create and drop the same database but no use.

I also dropped the same table but when I want to create it, it shows the same error again.

I'll be glad for any help

```
 CREATE DATABASE Music
 GO

 CREATE TABLE [Users](
 [User_ID] int NOT NULL identity (1,1) Primary key,
 [UserName] nvarchar (30) NOT NULL,
 [UserEmail] nvarchar (30) NOT NULL,
 [Password] nvarchar (30) NOT NULL
 )
 GO
```

Comment: Did you create the objects `Users` in the `model` databases at some point and therefore it's created in any new databases you created? I *assume* as well you are connected to the correct databases and not `master`. Show us the SQL you're running.

Comment: are you in the master db? what does `select db_name(), object_id('Users')` return?

Comment: @iptr it reruns no column name : master no column name : long number

Comment: I'm connceted to master @Larnu

Comment: @Larnu I'm not sure I understand your solution. I added the SQL table

Comment: You're creating a databases and then not connecting to it. You're then creating the table in `master` which is a system database, not a user database. `DROP` the table in `master` and then  after you've created the database connect to it. *Then* create your user objects. `CREATE DATABASE` just creates a database, it doesn't connect you to it. `USE` connects you to it.

Comment: After the create Database add a new line use Music GO

Comment: Thank you! thats solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE DATABASE Music GO

USE [Music]
GO

CREATE TABLE [Users]( [User_ID] int NOT NULL identity (1,1) Primary key, [UserName] 
nvarchar (30) NOT NULL, [UserEmail] nvarchar (30) NOT NULL, [Password] nvarchar (30) NOT NULL ) GO
```

you are creating the table in the database where you have the initial query to. See above to first switch to the new DB...